# Imported JSX component NewsСardMedium must be in PascalCase – isn't it?

Tags: reactjs, pascalcasing

I'm tired of endless warnings about PascalCase and unfortunately I found nothing in search, so decided to ask here - whats wrong with these components naming, aren't they already in PascalCase?

```
Imported JSX component NewsСardLarge must be in PascalCase
Imported JSX component NewsСardMedium must be in PascalCase  
Imported JSX component NewsСardSmall must be in PascalCase
```

the same goes for GridViewDesktop, GridViewTablet, etc..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is because you're using Cyrillic `С` (\u0421) instead of Latin `C` (\u0043) in your code.

- `NewsСardLarge` should be instead `NewsCardLarge`
- `NewsСardMedium` should be instead `NewsCardMedium`
- `NewsСardSmall` should be instead `NewsCardSmall`